# 2010 Movie about creatures that take over people in a small town, teenagers find out about it, try to save them using radio tower

Tags: story-identification, movie

Some scenes in the movie I remember:

1. Young guy first suspects his female teacher was taken over by creature while spying on her.
2. Teenagers are cornered in a small house and some of their friends got possessed by the creatures.
3. Two leads are seen running inside a radio station naked and possessed by creatures
4. End of the movie I think they find out that it wasn't just their town that got infected.

Comment: That's a good start. I recommend going [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and using the prompts to [edit] more details into your question. Also, please visit the [tour] to learn how to accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I just want to ask if this is color film or not.

Answer (score 2):

I found the movie... its Assimilate (2019). Three friends making a web series about their town discover that their neighbors are being killed and replaced by creatures who are perfect copies of their victims.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by copying and pasting in a synopsis from a site like IMDB or Wikipedia, and posting a link to the relevant page. [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/122024) offers some more tips on how to write a good story ID answer. You can also learn more about the site by taking the [tour].

Comment: And if you are the original querent, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) are the instructions for how to merge them so that you can accept.